# Screenshot of the visible part of the page in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, android-screen

In my application is a WebView widget, which opens a big page.
How do I capture the visible part of the page in WebView? `capturePicture()` is not suitable for it...

Answer (score 8):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapForVisibleRegion(WebView webview) {
    Bitmap returnedBitmap = null;
    webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    returnBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(webview.getDrawingCache());
    webview.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
    return returnedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: You saved my day. It seem to be applicable for an imageview as well

Answer (score 1):

Save your webView under bitmap. Then you save bitmap on SD card.

Use this to get your bitmap from webView :

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight(),Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable = view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null) 
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        else 
            canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Now just save it on SD and it's done

Comment: Your method works, but if the page in WebView scroll to middle, is a screenshot of the page top